# How can I resolve this compilation issues with WebClient in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, webclient

I'm using WebClient to download a file from a web url.
But vs is having this errors when compiling:
'wc' indentifier not declared (C2065)
'WebClient indentifier not declared (C2065)
Sintaxis error: identifier WebClient (C2061)
Left operand of '->DownloadFile' needs class/struct/union/generic

```c++
WebClient^ wc = gcnew WebClient; 
wc->DownloadFile("http://myweb.pw/file.dll","C:/tempdata/file.dll");
```

What can I do to use WebClient in VC++ .Net 4.5.2 to download a file from a url? Thank you!

Comment: is that hunk of code supposed to be c++ ?

Comment: it is vc++, yes

Comment: Have you got "System" assembly added as a Reference to your project?